# Syncronous AJAX stops on Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I do have AJAX request and in the success callback new function to rendergooglelinks and another AJAX calls are called.

And now, I try to change the asyncronous calls to syncronous using async: false in the AJAX request.

When I do a AJAX request, rendergooglelinks are not rendered due to "undefined" error and next ajax request works.

In the syncronous ajax request, progress stops after rendergooglelinks error. Next calls are not triggered. 
(i.e)  Codes after that error are not processed.

Whether syncronous ajax request stops on errors ?

Whether it behaves in the way of "strict" mode ?

How can we handle this ?

```
// syncronous request  
$.ajax({

    type:"GET",

    async: false,

    url: url,

    success: function(result, status, xhr) {

        rendergooglelinks();

        renderComments(); // this is not called due to error in the above 
    }

});

function rendergooglelinks() 
{

    google.test = ''; // returns error

}

function renderComments()
{

    // asyncronous request
    $.ajax({

        type:"GET",

        url: url,

        success: function(result, status, xhr) {

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: It is because AJAX request for redergooglelinks is depend on first request. so you need to do asynchronous call only.

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: @Mr.Duck added codes to the question.

Comment: @NandaKumar, what the purpose of making sync ajax call? Synchronous XHR on the main thread is deprecated

Comment: first: code in the question is not working the way you described. second: I think it could be XY problem. You just dont understand the way ajax calls working.

Comment: "Whether syncronous ajax request stops on errors ?". Ajax requests does not "stops" with errors. They "completes" with errors and calls callbacks/errorbacks. And callbacks and errorbacks - it is just js functions, no magick, just usual js flow

Comment: @Mr.Duck Purpose of Sync ajax call: To restrict the users to click multiple clicks on the various list without showing the overlay

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you posted, the error is that the variable `google` is never declared, so `google.test` cannot be assigned.
On the other hand, synchronous ajax calls are not a good practice, avoid them if possible.

Last but not last from [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) docs:

> Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are removed as of jQuery 3.0. You can use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.

For the `google` variable, i suggest you to pass it to the function as argument, is dangerous to assume that it exist no matter what.
For other errors, try this:

```
$.ajax({
  type:"GET",
  //async: false,
  url: url,
  /*success: function(result, status, xhr) {
    rendergooglelinks();
    renderComments(); // this is not called due to error in the above 
  }*/

}).then([ //success callbacks
    rendergooglelinks,
    renderComments
],[
    //no fail callbacks
]);

function rendergooglelinks(){
     google.test = ''; // returns error
}

function renderComments(){
    // asyncronous request
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET"
        url: url,
       /*success: function(result, status, xhr) {

       }*/
    }).done(function(result, status, xhr){
    });
}
```

See also [jQuery Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.deferred/)